# Load command from database

Tags: mysql, command, loading, discord.js

How can I load commands from the mysql database (for example columns: **id**, **command_name**, **aliases**, **content**)? These commands only have to **display the content** (photo or text).

For example:

DATABASE:
**id | command_name | aliases | content**

1  | test         | t, te   | Lorem ipsum...

I use command: **?test**

Result: Bot sent on the channel: **Lorem ipsum...**

Please help!

Comment: You probably want to do a bit more research, discord.js is part of Node.JS. You can use other NodeJS libraries to retreive the data from MySQL and use it.
Alternative post your JS code so we can help on specific issue.

Comment: I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: Good place to start https://discordjs.guide/#/sequelize/ It is example of SQLite, not MySQL, but principle the same.

Comment: How can it help me?

Comment: Look up something called "mongoose'. I highly suggest it for Discord Bots. Its a nodejs package that makes saving/getting/updating data in a Mongo Database very easy.

Comment: I'm using mysql, but I was thinking about mongodb. And what does the database have for what I want to do (loading commands from the database)?

Comment: I would like to do like mee6 - custom commands (https://imgur.com/a/9lwCwC4). 
I can add records to the database, but I do not know how to get the "buffer" command from the database?